# Xcode 8- build failed for manually created Swift Bridging header for renamed objective c project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have used swift `AppDelegate` file in my Objective-C project hence `Projectname-Bridging-Header.h` file created automatically. For some reasons, I changed my project name and I created my `newProjectname-Bridging-Header.h` file manually. But now I'm facing build time error:

> Swift Compiler Error- newProjectname-Bridging-Header does not exist.

I have set
 `"$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(PROJECT_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h"`

in `Targets->Buid Settings->Objective-C Bridging Header`.

How to solve this issue? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: Here, you have to give the path of your bridging header properly. Please check the location and name of your bridging header once and recheck accordingly

Comment: Once project is created , its name can not be changed. You have to create new project with new name and can use previous code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Bridge Header file name with path into Swift Compiler in Build settings.simply give Projectname with path like below instead of this "$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/$(PROJECT_NAME)-Bridging-Header.h"

Replace with ../ **(make sure the Bridge Header file name)**

> ../Projectname/Projectname-Bridging-Header.h

I tried to with custom name of Bridging-Header it works for me.
You can check here for more [Importing Swift into Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

[image]